# Auth and Uploading videos to Youtube API v3 using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, youtube-api

Can someone help me find a working code that goes through authorization and uploads a video?

Code below goes I'm able to get the access_token but when I paste it on the command line, it returns a "cb is not a function" error

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const readline = require('readline');
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/upload_app_session.json
const SCOPES = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
];
const TOKEN_DIR ='./';
const TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'upload_app_session.json';
const authorize = (credentials, cb) => {
const clientSecret = credentials.web.client_secret;
const clientId = credentials.web.client_id;
const redirectUrl = credentials.web.redirect_uris[0];
const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (error, token) => {
    if (error) {
        getNewToken(oauth2Client, cb);
    } else {
        oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
        cb(null, oauth2Client);
    }
});
};

const getNewToken = (oauth2Client, cb) => {
const authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
});
     console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', code => {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, (error, token) => {
        if (error) {
            cb(new Error('Error while trying to retrieve access token', error));
        } else {
            oauth2Client.credentials = token;
            storeToken(token);
            cb(null, oauth2Client);
        }
    });
});
};

const storeToken = token => {
try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
} catch (error) {
    if (error.code != 'EEXIST') {
        throw error;
        }
    }
    fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), error => {
         if (error) throw error;
         console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
     });
 };

module.exports = { authorize };
```

Tried the quickstart example from google developers but it didn't work either.